# Flow to Pull related records and create corresponding records

Tags: visual-workflow

I am sure this might be easy but I'm very new to flow and couldn't figure out how to achieve the below requirement and feeling trapped in a loop.

Requirement is:

When all of the necessary Subject records have been added to a Chronology, the user selects the ‘Find Events’ button which then fires a flow that finds all of the CONTACTS and Persons linked to the Chronology and then uses that list to find all relevant  Events. For each Event, a corresponding Chronology Item record is created

Data Model:

Chronology Items: lookup: Chronology AND Event

Subjects: lookup: Chronology, contact and Persons

I tried to this way:

1. Get records: Chronology with the record id
2. Get records from the subject with matching same record id
3. Get records: relevant events
4. loop: on event
5. create records for chronology items.

[image]

Maybe I'm failing to fetch the right records. any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Do you have to create Chronology records under the related Contacts -> events? I dont understand the object relationship, how are chronology, subject, contacts related?

Comment: Please [edit] to add detail to your question. What is your Flow currently doing? Can you add more specifics about what the expected outcome is? Are you receiving an error? Your description of the schema is also a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @anxiousAvocado data model mentioned.

Comment: @guljarshaikh it's not easy to understand from what you have mentioned, add more details on how objects are related. It's tough to follow the data model.

Comment: <aside> I know I've been reading too much Salesforce documentation, code, etc. when I read the OP's question and see the word "Subject", and the first thing I think is, "I should edit this - they misspelled `SObject`." </aside>

Comment: @Moonpie Now that I am rereading it, it makes sense lol but Subject still could be a custom object no way to know unless OP clarifies.

Comment: @guljarshaikh are you launching the flow when Chronology record is CREATED or Created and Edited both?

Comment: @anxiousAvocado its auto-launched on the button click which is on chronology (this is bcz its in requirement)

Comment: @guljarshaikh can you provide answers to all the question, Is is auto launched on created or create and edit? it's tough for people to answer to your question if you can't provide enough information.

Comment: @anxiousAvocado done. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the flow you should use :

Get all contacts for Chronology -> Loop through each contact -> get all Events AND -> Store each event in a new List -> loop through the LIST OF EVENTS -> create a chronology item record.

[image]

Comment: anxiousAvocado, please do not ask people to select your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: @David Cheng do or dont? Because I asked OP to select it as correct answer if it was correct. Not sure I understand.

Comment: sorry, do not ask.

Comment: Got it . Thanks

Comment: anxiousAvocado -- [background on etiquette for answers](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed). We appreciate your answers as they help the Community.

Comment: @cropredy that was actually helpful, thank you. I appreciate that.